# manipulator missing from project but visible in new ones

Tags: 3d-view, 3d-manipulator, gizmo

iam working on a project and for some reason the manipulator is gone (it was working for some days on the project but it disappeared) i tried all the solutions of the common problems but it did work i tried with 3d cursor and bounding box and still not seen

[image: viewport overlays]

[image: viewport gizmos]

[image: bounding box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok seems like its a bug in the program and the only solution for it is to append all the objects to a new project (thats blender support team response)

Comment: If you really think that this is a bug, please report it here: https://developer.blender.org/